# Solaris shell script how to use variable inside command

Tags: bash, shell, variables, solaris

I am trying to create a small **shell script** in `Solaris` which checks the number of connections per month for the current logged in user, but I am having problem in **using a variable inside a command** in the right way.

This is my script:

```
current_user=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
echo The logins for user \"$current_user\" were:
echo January: 
last | awk '$1=="${current_user}" && $5=="Jan" {count++} END {print count}'
echo February: 
last | awk '$1=="${current_user}" && $5=="Feb" {count++} END {print count}'
.
.
.
```

and it prints:

```
The logins for user "username" were:
January:

February:

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables to awk using the `-v` option, for example:

```
last | awk -vuser="$current_user" '$1==user && $5=="Jan" {count++} END {print count}'
```

Alternatively, you could break out of the single quoted string:

```
last | awk '$1=="'"${current_user}"'" && $5=="Jan" {count++} END {print count}'
```

Comment: Thank you! The second option worked, but I am trying to find out why the first one didn't.

Comment: @Manos Which Solaris version of `awk` are you using?  There are multiple different versions of `awk` on a normal Solaris install. The default one is pretty old.

Comment: @Andrew Henle It has an oawk version.